# Displaying datetime in GMT server wide in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I have a website in which all records are inserted according to server datetime which is around 6 hours behind GMT. I want to display those datetimes in GMT without changing insertion datetime. I mean is there any global setting in PHP which will allow me to display datetime in GMT without affecting every line where I am displaying datetime?
And I also don't want to change the insert script which will continue to insert datetime according to what ever current timezone is.

Thanks

Comment: I like this question, hopefully you get an anwser +1 Buddy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is only one global timezone setting for PHP:

```
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = America/Los_Angeles
```

It affects both parsing and rendering, so changing this value will affect all of your dates.

If you just care about display, you can use the `gmdate()` function to render GMT dates. It works exactly like the `date()` function, except it renders the dates in GMT instead. See [the gmdate documentation](http://us.php.net/gmdate) for more details.

Comment: This is one solution but the problem is like you said it will also affect insert dates which means the moment I change timezone in this file, from them onwards all new datetime will insert and show in GMT format, but datetime already inserted in database will remain was it is which will create confusion.

Comment: @Ali You don't need to change the timezone to use `gmdate` to display them as GMT dates.

Comment: Yes but that means I will have to change that in every file where date is being displayed!?

Comment: @Ali Yes, unfortunately. If you are using `date` now, there is no way around this. If you are using DateTime objects, you can use one of the other answers to modify the timezone before reading/writing from the DB.

Comment: @Ali if you are using date everywhere, then this is probably you're easiest option. You can use a tool/IDE to do a find/replace on all your files. +1

Answer (score 1):

You will need to modify the timezone of any datetimes you pull out that are server time, you **cannot** modify the default timezone (completely anyway, see the procedural approach that changes it and sets it back again). There are 3 options described below.

I'd recommend using the DateTIme object as it offers the greatest simplicity and flexibility.

---

**Using The [DateTime](http://au.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) Object**

You shouldn't do anything when you create the DateTime, so it creates it with the server timezone, but then you need to call [setTimezone](http://au.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php).

Here's an example:

```
// Could just call this once, and use a reference to it.
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('GMT');

$insertDate = new DateTime($row['insertDate']);
$insertDate->setTimezone($timezone);
```

Now `$insertDate` would be in the GMT timezone converted from whatever your server's timezone is.

---

**Using Procedural [Date/Time Functions](http://au.php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php)**

If you want to use the procedural functions, in your case you could use [gmdate](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) or if you needed another timezone other than GMT you would have to continuously change the default timezone using [date_default_timezone_set](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

```
// Storing so you can restore the current default
$serverTimezone = date_default_timezone_get();

/** 
 * Get the unix timestamp for the insertDate
 * This converts from the default timezone to UTC
 */
$insertDate = strtotime($row['insertDate']);


date_default_timezone_set('GMT');

/**
 * This displays the date in the new default timezone GMT, based
 * on the UTC timezone of the unix timestamp
 */
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $insertDate);

// Reset the timezone
date_default_timezone_set($serverTimezone);
```

This could be abstracted into its own function to save you the hassle.

---

**Using [gmdate](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) - Only works for GMT**

Similar concept as the procedural example shown above, except we don't need to play with the default timezone.

```
/** 
 * Get the unix timestamp for the insertDate
 * This converts from the default timezone to UTC
 */
$insertDate = strtotime($row['insertDate']);

/**
 * This displays the date in GMT, based
 * on the UTC timezone of the unix timestamp
 */
echo gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', $insertDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [date.timezone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone)

In your php.ini, add the following line:

```
date.timezone = "Etc/GMT-6"
```

To see all the potential formats, check out [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)